# What would a stovetop "jet-powered infrared gas-range burner" look like and how would it work? Is heating really only via thermal infrared radiation?

Tags: alternatives, cooking, natural-gas

NPR's February 4, 2023 podcast with transcript [Gas stove makers have a pollution solution. They're just not using it](https://www.npr.org/2023/02/04/1149736969/gas-stove-makers-have-a-pollution-solution-theyre-just-not-using-it) mentions:

> The natural gas industry saw regulators' interest and worried the CPSC might come for gas cooking stoves next, according to [a 1984 Science News article](https://www.sciencenews.org/archive/cleaner-cooking-gas). That prompted two industry research groups to begin working on burner improvements.
>
> Out of that process emerged a "jet-powered infrared gas-range burner."
>
> Instead of the iconic blue flame that you normally see at a gas stove, the infrared burner had "a flat ceramic plate... honeycombed with window-screen-like perforations," according to the article. Air and fuel burned as they were sent across the plate and ignited bright red in a way that makes the flame itself difficult to see.
>
> This infrared burner consumed about 40% less natural gas to reach cooking temperatures and emitted 40% less nitrogen oxides. The Science News article said designers touted another benefit of the infrared burner: a kitchen stays cooler because more energy goes into the cooking vessel instead of the room.
>
> A Pennsylvania-based stove manufacturer, Caloric Corporation, expressed interest in the infrared burner. That company is no longer in business and was absorbed into Whirlpool Corporation, which did not respond to multiple inquiries about why the burner was never offered in retail stoves.

**Question:** What would a stovetop "jet-powered infrared gas-range burner" look like and how would it work? Is the pan actually heated primarily by infrared radiation, or is conduction from the hot surface and/or contact with the flame also providing heat transfer?

Comment: How is your question not answered by your linked article?  In particular the second figure, [that I put here](https://i.imgur.com/RoVmpE7.png), seems to answer most of your question.

Comment: @User65535 1) I'd looked at that but I can't really understand what's going on, can you? *Is heating really only via thermal infrared radiation?* I think there's a good chance that there's someone here who can better than I, and 2) remember [@uhoh's lemma #3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377004/303080) the primary goal of a Stack Exchange question is to generate answers not only for the OP to read but for many future readers as well.

Comment: The paragraph that seems to explain it precisely [I have put here](https://i.imgur.com/rGlsOMI.png), perhaps explain what is not clear.

Comment: [The paragraph before is also relevant](https://i.imgur.com/F3niGRd.png)

Comment: @User65535 if you think those paragraphs are sufficiently clear, and address my question you are welcome to summarize in an answer post!